# How to use LINQ to group by and select top record?

Tags: c#, linq

I am struggling to get a linq statement that gives me a single record for each player with the largest Count.

My goal here would be to display 2 records:

| Player | Tag | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Player1 | Orange | 2 |
| Player2 | Apple | 1 |

I have a query 1 that seems to flatten the tags.
Then with query 2 I am producing a grouped Count for player and tag.

Is there a way to just select the top record for each player?

```
void Main()
{
    Player p1 = new Player { Name = "Player1" };
    Player p2 = new Player { Name = "Player2" };
    List<PlayerAnswerRecord> UsedWords = new List<PlayerAnswerRecord>();
    UsedWords.Insert(0, new PlayerAnswerRecord { Word = new DictionaryEntry{ Word = "fruit", Tags = new List<string>{"apple", "orange"} }, Player = p1, Score = 10, RecordType = AnserRecordType.Valid });
    UsedWords.Insert(0, new PlayerAnswerRecord { Word = new DictionaryEntry{ Word = "fruit2", Tags = new List<string>{"pineapple", "orange"} }, Player = p1, Score = 10, RecordType = AnserRecordType.Valid });
    UsedWords.Insert(0, new PlayerAnswerRecord { Word = new DictionaryEntry{ Word = "fruity", Tags = new List<string>{"apple", "orange"} }, Player = p2, Score = 25, RecordType = AnserRecordType.Valid });
    
    foreach(var w in UsedWords)
    {
        //Console.WriteLine(w.Word.Word);
    }
    
    //UsedWords.GroupBy(
    var grouped =
        from entry in UsedWords
        group entry by entry.Player into newGroup
        select newGroup;
    
    //Console.Write(grouped);
    
    var query = UsedWords
        .Select(x=> new {x.Player, x.Word})
        .SelectMany(x=> x.Word.Tags);
        
    var query1 = UsedWords.SelectMany (
      c => c.Word.Tags, 
      (c, o) => 
         new  
         {
            Player = c.Player.Name, 
            Tag = o
         }
   ); 
    //var query2 = query1.GroupBy(x=>x.Name).Select(group => new {Metric = group.Key, Count = group.Count()});  
    var query2 = query1.GroupBy(x=> new {x.Player, x.Tag}).Select(group => new {Player = group.Key.Player, Tag = group.Key.Tag, Count = group.Count()}).OrderByDescending(x=>x.Count);
    //var query2 = query1.GroupBy(x=>x.Name).Select(group => group, (group, o) => new {Metric = group.Key, Count = group.Count()});
    var query3 = query2.Max(x => x.Count);
    Console.Write(query1);
    Console.Write(query2);
    Console.Write(query3);
}

// You can define other methods, fields, classes and namespaces here

public class PlayerAnswerRecord
{
    public Player Player;
    public DictionaryEntry Word;
    public int Score;
    public float ElapsedTime;
    public AnserRecordType RecordType;
}

public enum AnserRecordType
{
    Valid,
    Invalid,
    OutOfTime,
    UsedWord
}

public class DictionaryEntry
{
    public string Word;
    public List<string> Tags;
}

public class Player
{
    public string Name;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with breaking down the query into multiple parts. LINQ uses deferred execution (i.e. queries are not executed when they are declared, they are executed when the output is iterated) so you can split your query into as many steps as you like and it won't affect the result or performance.

But if you really want to write one query, you could use the following:

```
var result =
    from entry in UsedWords
    from tags in entry.Word.Tags
    group tags by entry.Player.Name
    into tagsGroupedByPlayer
    let mostFrequentTag = (from tags in tagsGroupedByPlayer
        group tags by tags
        into tags
        select new { Tag = tags.Key, Count = tags.Count() } into tagAndCount
        orderby tagAndCount.Count 
        select tagAndCount).First()
    select new { Player = tagsGroupedByPlayer.Key, Tag = mostFrequentTag.Tag, Count = mostFrequentTag.Count };
```

Obviously you are free to modify the final `select` clause to project the result into whatever format you wish.

Comment: that worked once I added in a sort by descending. Thanks!